# Непонятый шрифт на вкладке конкурсов

Tags: дефект, дизайн, конкурс

Имеется картинка того как выглядят вкладки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

либо у меня что-то с глазами либо цифра в вкладке похожа на ребёнка цифры 9 и 8 :)

Comment: Не знаю, мне сегодня показалось что гугле шрифт поменялся ;D (и он наверно все-таки поменялся, либо я двинулся)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, в любом случае мне кажется выглядит странновато )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто она очень мелкая. Вообще, по форме понятно, что это 9, т. к. верхняя часть явно больше нижней.

И вообще, на скриншоте она стала страшной из-за артефактов jpg (как они оказались в png?), на странице вполне чёткая. Вот так она выглядит при масштабе 400%:

[image: скриншот 400%]

Comment: в png она оказалась после вырезки из скриншота)) я просто этот вопрос опубликовал чтобы может починили немного (не знаю что именно тут чинить) :D

Comment: @Andrew, а я сначала подумал, что её transform'ом центрируют и она смазалась.

Comment: можно увеличить немного